# How do I reconcile this contradiction about an NPC's actions in the Curse of Strahd adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, npc, curse-of-strahd

In the description for [Ezmerelda D'Avenir](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/appendix-d-monsters-and-npcs#EzmereldadAvenir) on page 230 of the *Curse of Strahd* adventure, it says

> Though van Richten could have done them harm, he instead interrogated Ezmerelda's mother and father on the wereabouts of his missing son. Satisfied with their answers, **he spared their lives before departing** [...]

However, it says in the "Journal of Rudolph van Richten" handout on page 255 (in [Appendix F](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/appendix-f-handouts)):

> When I found the caravan, I threatened to set the zombies on the Vistani unless they returned my dear boy. They replied that he had been sold to the vampire, Baron Metus. Something inside me snapped. **I released the zombies, and the entire tribe was eaten alive.**

So which of the above is correct:

> **Did van Richten kill the tribe with zombies? Or did he spare them and walk away?**

Obviously Ezmerelda survived, but

> I imagine she wouldn't be fond of van Richten if he slaughtered her entire tribe, yet why would he lie? Is it guilt that he didn't kill them so he's covering his tracks? Is it the senile ravings of a old man (though he seems pretty sound of mind to me)? Or is Ezmerelda mistaken, and her family were illusions for several years (that doesn't sound right)?

How is one able to figure this out? Does it say somewhere in the book that the journal lies, or that Ezmerelda is under some sort of enchantment?